# Overlapping Two DIVS Horizontally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have two divs within a table cell (making a Timeline) and I need them to overlap rather then come under each-other.

The position attribute of all DIVs inside the cell has to remain the same (because of a drag/drop JQUERY plugin I used)

[Link to Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ianfc89/4DW6y/2/)

[Link to Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ianfc89/JDff9/11/)

```
       <tr style="border:1px; height:30px;">
        <td style="border:1px solid black; position:static">
            <div  style="margin-left:0;width:50px;display:inline;position:relative">
                <div style="background-color: green; position:absolute">
                    Div1
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-left:0px;width:20px;display: inline; position:relative">
                <div style="background-color: red; position:absolute">
                Div2
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

I need both DIVs to be start relavtive from the edge of the cell.

Thanks

Comment: All of these inline styles are for the purpose of this question....... right?

Comment: Was playing around with this tonight, if you pull the styles out to a class I think it kind of works like you're wanting. Updating answer

Comment: thanks if you find anything let me know please :)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell you just need to push the red `<div>` down a bit. And since you've positioned it absolutely, it's easily done with `top`:

```
<div style="background-color: red; position:absolute; top:10px;">
```

Check [this update](http://jsfiddle.net/4DW6y/7/) on your jsFiddle

Comment: hi i made a bit of a mistake in my fiddle width is defined in inner div because that needs to span across cells. they are not overlapping for me here is updated fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/ianfc89/4DW6y/13/

Comment: Just adjust the top then, make it smaller. I'm struggling to understand what your trying to do now..

Comment: Sorry rather tried :) so let me try to explain. the outer divs are placeholders for the inner divs. The outer divs bind to a table cell and the inner ones hold timeline information (ie could span across multiple cells, but starts from contained cell with outerdiv). Say two timeline elements are in the same cell, i need them to start after each other (aligned) not with a <br> and come under each other. http://jsfiddle.net/ianfc89/JDff9/11/ Here DIV Green and Red should over lap not come under eachother.

Comment: I managed the following but the second div (green one) won't start from the beginning of the table cell http://jsfiddle.net/ianfc89/JDff9/13/

Comment: I think he wants the green div to start in the second Td

Comment: no i dont. i want the green div to start with the red one, at the moment it is offset by 5px. Say i add three divs http://jsfiddle.net/ianfc89/JDff9/15/

Comment: Right ontop overlap eachother with no offset )

Answer (score 0):

They're going to be stacked like this, you should also be able to float the divs and set z-index explicitly to stack them.

http://jsfiddle.net/ianfc89/JDff9/13/

HTML

```
<body onload="REDIPS.drag.init()">
<script>
    REDIPS.drag.dropMode = 'multiple';
</script>
<div id="drag" class="containDiv">
    <table class="tableWhole">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="tableCell">
                    <div style="position:relative">
                    <div id="A125_Contain" class="drag progressContainer" >
                        <div id="A125" style="cursor: move; background-color: red; width: 500px; height: 20px; ">A125</div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="B125_Contain" class="drag progressContainer" >
                        <div id="B125" style="cursor: move; background-color: green; width: 100px; height: 20px;  ">A125</div>
                    </div>
                        <div>
                </td>
                <td class="tableCell"></td>
                <td class="tableCell"></td>
                <td class="tableCell"></td>
                <td class="tableCell"></td>
                <td class="tableCell"></td>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Styles

```
.containDiv {
}
.tableWhole {
    width:1000px;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
.tableCell {
    width:300px;
    height:60px;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.progressContainer
{
 display:inline; border-bottom-style: none; position: relative; top: 0px; left:              0px; width: 100px; height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer :) but unfortunately I can't have that outer div. have you got any solutions with keeping to my original structure. Try drag a div out of the cell, and put it back in. http://jsfiddle.net/ianfc89/haDmZ/

Comment: Hm, you can make the <Td>'s position:relative and get a similar effect but you still can't drag one off then back ontop of another. I'm low on ideas at the moment, maybe someone can come along with a better solution.

Comment: thanks for helping Andrew :) if I don't get any ideas i will re-ask the question and try to explain it a bit better :)